# Can´t connect to Web Service from Android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ip

I'm quite new to `Android` and `WebServices` and at the moment I'm reading many info about Web Services, SOAP, etc.

I'm trying to write a Web Service example that just says Hello and it works in my browser but from my Android device/emulator doesn't work. I have set its IP to my PC ipv4 address and I have turned off the firewall and the antivirus. However if in the browser I try to connect to this IP it says 404. (I don't know if this is normal) I'm also using local IIS with the following URL: `http://localhost/HelloAndroid` .

Here is the code of my Web Service:

```
namespace HelloAndroid
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://sample.com/")]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello, Android from .NET";
        }
    }
}
```

Android Activity:

```
public class SoapTestActivity extends Activity {
    TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";    
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.35/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx";

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);            
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new      SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultValue = response.toString();

            result.setText(resultValue);          
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi there, my knowledge of the Android emulator isn't the greatest but if on your emulator you go to the browser and do `http://10.0.2.2/HelloAndroid` (or `http://10.0.2.2/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx`) do you still get a 404 error?

Comment: And make sure you read and understand this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: nkvu, I still get that error and I also added "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />" in the manifest

Comment: Hi there, what about just accessing `http://10.0.2.2` from the web browser on your emulator? If IIS is up and running it should serve out the IIS welcome page...

Comment: Thank you nvku but this doesn't work either

Comment: Does your browser just present another 404? It's a bit strange because `10.0.2.2` should [loopback](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) to your local development machine where IIS is running so I would expect at least the IIS welcome page to appear. It's not a direct solution but instead of calling your locally developed .asmx what if you follow the steps and reference the one in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap) article? Are you able to call that successfully?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to check direct access to web services through http://192.168.1.35/HelloAndroid/Service1.asmx from your internet browser on the server machine.
If it's okay, then try to correct client side (soap request and response) code.
Else, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554996/cant-access-web-api-with-ipport-but-can-with-localhostport-during-vs-debug-mo) to make access to server first.
If problem exists try this:
Register framework from the control panel:

Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Information Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > Select ASP.NET 4.5 (version you use)

Click OK.

Done!