# Why can't I connect to IISExpress from my Android device?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am trying to connect to a ASP.NET WebApi service running on IISExpress through Visual Studio from an Android emulator (Genymotion specifically). I was able to set up my IISExpress bindings and firewall (as shown in posts similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192726/android-emulator-loopback-to-iis-express-does-not-work-but-does-work-with-cassi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554996/cant-access-web-api-with-ipport-but-can-with-localhostport-during-vs-debug-mo)) so that I could access the website externally.

I was able to successfully navigate to the service from another laptop on the network, but am still unable to accomplish it from the browser in the emulator or my own Android device (also on the network). When I try this I get a generic "Web page may not be available" message. Why can I access it from other external machines, but not the mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Android is not able to resolve Windows hostnames so when I set up the binding to use my machine name it did not work. Once I changed it to use my IP address it was fixed.