# I get a 503 Error using the IP, but not when using the host name. IIS ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, server, lan

I am using IIS and my web application is asp.net created using visual studio 2017.

To the bindings I've added both 'any available'(*) and my local IP.

I Start the website and success! I can access it via the Hostname I have set.

Unfortunately, I can't access it via the IP and neither can other machines on the network. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Is it a certificate thing?

Comment: No. I have selected HTTP for both bindings

Comment: Appears related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554996/cant-access-web-api-with-ipport-but-can-with-localhostport-during-vs-debug-mo

Comment: I have tried this too. still getting the same 503 error.

Comment: Run Binding Diagnostics to learn the bindings, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html 503 indicates that the request goes to another site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I edited the ApplicationHost.config file

```
<application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="website-location" />
</application>
```

Then I got an error in the published (improvement...) web app's web.config file, which I solved using: [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs) about the exact issue.